# How to achieve pagination?

Tags: android

I am dealing with huge data (downloading from webserver to client/phone). Currently I am trying to parse and load complete data into sqlite database when the application launches.

This is taking a lot of time. I want to load the data based on the screen navigation.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean with _based on the screen navigation_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pass information between your server and the device as XML.
This way the device can request URLs for specific information such as `example.com/news/latest` (return headlines of the latest 20 news articles), `example.com/news/americas` (the latest 20 article headlines from the Americas) or `example.com/news/article/177309/` (one full article).

The server can then query its database for the needed information based on the query and output it for the client as XML. The client can parse the XML and add the data to it's local SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not restricting the dataset returned from the source first, *then* downloading it onto the client device?

Comment: Hi MHTri,
Yes, this will restrict the amount of data retrieved from the source first but I believe user experience will be better as it takes lesser time compared to loading the whole data at one go. Please suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: Without more details of your current implementation I cannot offer any more advice. Look into how you can separate your data from the source, and then figure out how you can request the separated data from the app. 
For example, if you know that each page in your app displays 100 records, and if you're getting the data from SQL, then the command would be something like SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = startIndex, where your startIndex is your page number * 100.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance boost up , i prefer running an async task in  which the data gets uploaded or downloaded to the server. Its similar to threads but much better.